# How to plot boxplots per each categorical variable wrapping by another categorical variable in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to use this chunk of code to create a plot in R. I want to get one frame for each variable in `Offensive_Statistic` with boxplots per each variable in `Jet_Lag_boolean` representing the distributions in `Measure`

```
    ggplot(data=df_off_plots, aes(y=Jet_Lag_boolean, x=Measure)) + geom_boxplot() +
  xlab("Measurement Value")+
  facet_wrap( ~ Offensive_Statistic, scales="free_y")+
  theme_bw() + ylab(" Number of Time Zones Crossed")  + coord_flip()
```

I am getting the overall structure correctly but my boxplots are only lines  as you can seee here: [image]

I am adding a reproducible dataset:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Measure = sample(0:999),
  Jet_Lag_boolean = sample(c("1", "0"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
  Offensive_Statistic = sample(c('OPA', 'OA', 'SLG'), 1000, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I am getting the same error:

[image]

Comment: Please, make a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: OK, I did it, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You got the `x` & `y` orders backward

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = Data, aes(y = Measure, x = Jet_Lag_boolean)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  # geom_jitter() +
  facet_wrap(~ Offensive_Statistic, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_bw() + 
  # coord_flip() +
  ylab("Measurement Value") +
  xlab("Number of Time Zones Crossed")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>